# A question about syncing the IPad with Win XP and Win 8.1

Tags: itunes, backup

I use an IPad, a Windows XP SP3 desktop and a Windows 8.1 laptop. I usually use the IPad and I delete emails from there. I do not know how to sync all three of these machines to get rid of the deleted emails and update everything else. Can someone tell me how to do this? I am new at this syncing thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using POP3 or IMAP for your email?

If your service is **POP3**, then each machine will download emails unread by that machine, up to the retention limit of the mail server.
This means that you will always have to manually delete each email from each machine.

There is the possibility that you can adjust the retention limit, to reduce the amount of backlog that is downloaded. The retention period usually starts **after** the first device has downloaded that particular message, so you don't lose any mail if no machine picks up messages for a few days etc. You would need to ask your Service Provider how to do that.

If you use **IMAP**, then the emails actually always live on the remote server, so any action you take will be reflected across any machine that accesses that remote data.

Which of those services you use is usually not choosable by the user, it's in the hands of your Service Provider.